# How to build that a message have seen delivered from a Form in HTML /JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making my little website and added in it the Contact Form.
I added code in HTML and Javascript that it can be delivered and a complete way succesfully but I do not know how to add in my Js file or/and html file to say the user that it was delivered succesfully.for it, Could you help me to do it? Thanks for your time and sorry for my little english....
This is my Js code

```
formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'),
        nombre = formulario.nombre,
        email = formulario.email,
        texto = formulario.texto,
        error = document.getElementById('error');

    function validarNombre(e){
        if(nombre.value == '' || nombre.value == null){
            console.log('Por favor completa el nombre');
            error.style.display = 'block';
            error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa el nombre</li>';

            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            error.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function validarEmail(e){
        if(email.value == '' || email.value == null){
            console.log('Por favor completa tu direccion de email');
            error.style.display = 'block';
            error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa tu direccion de email</li>';

            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            error.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function validarTexto(e){
        if(texto.value == '' || texto.value == null){
            console.log('Por favor completa el mensaje');
            error.style.display = 'block';
            error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa el mensaje</li>';

            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            error.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }


    function validarFormulario(e){
        error.innerHTML = '';

        validarNombre(e);
        validarEmail(e);
        validarTexto(e);


    }

    formulario.addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario);
```

Comment: How can JavaScript know if the message was delivered or not?

Comment: I guessed that I had to add the code in the Js File. Maybe I have to add it in my Html file, If it is like that, Could you help to me to add it there? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you can add a div at the top of your html page with a `<p>` element that will contain the text:

`<div><p class="message"></p></div>`

Then add an onsubmit attribute to your form like this: 
`<form onsubmit="success()" action="#"></form>`.

In your js file, the success function should change the text content to add your success message like this:

```
function success() {
  document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Your success message"
}
```

A more rudimentary approach is to simply alert the message when the form is submitted like this: ```

Comment: Hey, I checked your problem and you need to remove this part:                     ```<form onsubmit="success()" action="#">```. What you need to do is add the onsubmit="success()" part to your existing form like this: ```<form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario" name ="formulario" onsubmit="success()"> ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you but your suggest is not working for me. I did what you told me but Possibly I am making a mistake. I added the html lines code (please see the code, these one are maked with -------) and the Javascript function in my Js file. Hopefully you can understand me and thanks again for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>VR Health</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">


</head>
<body>
-------------------<div><p class="message"></p></div>------------------------------------
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Barra Logo + Menu -->
            <div class="row nav rounded-top align-items-stretch justify-content-between">
                <!-- Logotipo -->
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg logo d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                    <h2>VR HEALTH</h2>
                    <span class="icono icon-dot"></span>
                    <p>VIRTUAL REALITY AT THE SERVICE OF HEALTH</p>
                </div>

                <nav class="col-md-12 col-lg-auto menu d-flex align-items-stretch flex-wrap flex-sm-nowrap">
                    <a href="#uno" class="c-1 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
                            <span>Our Mission</span>
                            <i class="icono icon-briefcase"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#dos" class="c-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
                            <span>About Us</span>
                            <i class="icono icon-user"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#tres" class="c-3 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
                            <span>Contact</span>
                            <i class="icono icon-mail"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Video -->
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- 21:9 .embed-responsive-21by9 -->
                    <!-- 16:9 .embed-responsive-16by9 -->
                    <!-- 4:3 .embed-responsive-4by3 -->
                    <!-- 1:1 .embed-responsive-1by1 -->
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/370303345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen loop></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Seccion Portafolio -->
            <div class="row portafolio ">
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="col">
                    <h2 id="uno" class="titulo">Our Mission</h2>
                    <div class="row galeria justify-content-center">
                    <p class = "text-justify" >Our mission is to help people who are not having a good time on health issues. Virtual Reality Video Games will allow to these people to recover in a fun way and empower to them to make their recovery more enjoyable and effective. We have a lot of work ahead but we are very happy to have in our hands a very powerful tool and it will give people a better quality of life.</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            <!-- Seccion Acerca de -->
            <div class="row acerca-de align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 foto">
                    <img src="img/LogoVR200x200.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" alt="">
                    </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 info">
                    <h2 id="dos" class="titulo">About Us</h2>
                    <p class = "text-justify">Our experience is oriented to the creation of Video Games and Apps in Virtual Reality.Given the impressive advancement of this technology and the wide possibilities offered by this to issues related to Health, as well as to our vocation to help people who have problems of this kind, that is why we are working together with specialists on issues related to different pathologies, developing Recovery Treatments for people with Motor and Cognitive problems in a totally different way from the current ones, achieving immersion in a playful environment and reducing frustration and depression(to mention some of the benefits) and improving living conditions of those who use them.
                    For this, we have the best equipment and we can work the human body in an integral way and cover a wide spectrum of diseases.</p>

                    </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Seccion Contacto -->
            <div class="row contacto justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                    <h2 id="tres" class="titulo">Contact</h2>
                    <form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario" name ="formulario">
--------------------<form onsubmit="success()" action="#">-------------------------------
                    <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Name/Last Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <textarea name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Write your question here..."></textarea>

                        <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>

                        <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Redes Sociales -->
            <div class="row redes-sociales justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/VrhealthA"  target="_blank" class="icono icon-twitter twitter"></a>
                    <a href="https://linkedin.com/company/vr-health/?viewAsMember=true "target=_blank " class="icono icon-instagram instagram"></a>
                    <a href="https://facebook.com/VR-Health-105840090781610" target="_blank" class="icono icon-facebook facebook"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```